# Issue continuing a DeepLearning Model from Checkpoint in H2O-3.38.0.1

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I have started to receive the following error several months and several checkpoints into training a model from the same checkpoint script. I am triggering the checkpoint script from R-4.2.1 using the H2O Build project version: 3.38.0.1. My data is stored in gzip files, is it possible that the parse of the imported data bundles is not working as expected?

Java error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearningModel$DeepLearningParameters$Sanity.checkIfParameterChangeAllowed(DeepLearningModel.java:2047)
at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.buildModel(DeepLearning.java:286)
at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.computeImpl(DeepLearning.java:234)
at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:252)
at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.compute2(DeepLearning.java:224)
at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1677)
at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:976)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

I am using a multinode cloud:

R is connected to the H2O cluster:
H2O cluster uptime:         5 minutes 31 seconds
H2O cluster timezone:       America/Chicago
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.38.0.1
H2O cluster version age:    7 months and 13 days !!!
H2O cluster name:           ClusterName1
H2O cluster total nodes:    2
H2O cluster total memory:   886.12 GB
H2O cluster total cores:    80
H2O cluster allowed cores:  72
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
H2O Connection ip:          localhost
H2O Connection port:        54321
H2O Connection proxy:       NA
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
R Version:                  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)

Checkpoint Script:

```
model <- h2o.loadModel("file:/D://Users/Mxi102517")

Mx <-  h2o.deeplearning(
  model_id = "Mx"
, checkpoint = model@model_id
, x=x
, y=y
, training_frame = trainBundle.h2o
, validation_frame = validBundle.h2o
, activation = "RectifierWithDropout"
, hidden = c(5120,5120)
, epochs=10
, train_samples_per_iteration=-2
, target_ratio_comm_to_comp = 0.1
, adaptive_rate=TRUE
, rho=0.9995
, stopping_metric="AUC"
, stopping_rounds = 5
, stopping_tolerance = 1e-5
, shuffle_training_data = TRUE
, use_all_factor_levels = TRUE
, sparse = TRUE
, ignore_const_cols = FALSE
, quiet_mode=F)
```

Imported Model Parameters:
|label|type|level|actual_value|
|model_id|Key|critical|Mx|
|training_frame|Key|critical|·|
|validation_frame|Key|critical|·|
|nfolds|int|critical|0|
|keep_cross_validation_models|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|keep_cross_validation_predictions|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|fold_assignment|enum|secondary|·|
|fold_column|VecSpecifier|secondary|·|
|response_column|VecSpecifier|critical|Flag|
|ignored_columns|string[]|critical|SID|
|ignore_const_cols|boolean|critical|FALSE|
|score_each_iteration|boolean|secondary|FALSE|
|weights_column|VecSpecifier|secondary|·|
|offset_column|VecSpecifier|secondary|·|
|balance_classes|boolean|secondary|FALSE|
|class_sampling_factors|float[]|expert|·|
|max_after_balance_size|float|expert|5|
|max_confusion_matrix_size|int|secondary|20|
|checkpoint|Key|secondary|·|
|pretrained_autoencoder|Key|expert|·|
|overwrite_with_best_model|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|use_all_factor_levels|boolean|secondary|TRUE|
|standardize|boolean|secondary|TRUE|
|activation|enum|critical|RectifierWithDropout|
|hidden|int[]|critical|51205120|
|epochs|double|critical|10|
|train_samples_per_iteration|long|secondary|-2|
|target_ratio_comm_to_comp|double|expert|0.1|
|seed|long|expert|4535434575234920000|
|adaptive_rate|boolean|secondary|TRUE|
|rho|double|expert|0.9995|
|epsilon|double|expert|0.00000001|
|rate|double|expert|0.005|
|rate_annealing|double|expert|0.000001|
|rate_decay|double|expert|1|
|momentum_start|double|expert|0|
|momentum_ramp|double|expert|1000000|
|momentum_stable|double|expert|0|
|nesterov_accelerated_gradient|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|input_dropout_ratio|double|secondary|0|
|hidden_dropout_ratios|double[]|secondary|·|
|l1|double|secondary|0|
|l2|double|secondary|0|
|max_w2|float|expert|3.4028235E+38|
|initial_weight_distribution|enum|expert|UniformAdaptive|
|initial_weight_scale|double|expert|1|
|initial_weights|Key[]|expert|·|
|initial_biases|Key[]|expert|·|
|loss|enum|secondary|Automatic|
|distribution|enum|secondary|bernoulli|
|quantile_alpha|double|secondary|0.5|
|tweedie_power|double|secondary|1.5|
|huber_alpha|double|secondary|0.9|
|score_interval|double|secondary|5|
|score_training_samples|long|secondary|10000|
|score_validation_samples|long|secondary|0|
|score_duty_cycle|double|secondary|0.1|
|classification_stop|double|expert|0|
|regression_stop|double|expert|0.000001|
|stopping_rounds|int|secondary|5|
|stopping_metric|enum|secondary|AUC|
|stopping_tolerance|double|secondary|0.00001|
|max_runtime_secs|double|secondary|0|
|score_validation_sampling|enum|expert|Uniform|
|diagnostics|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|fast_mode|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|force_load_balance|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|variable_importances|boolean|critical|TRUE|
|replicate_training_data|boolean|secondary|TRUE|
|single_node_mode|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|shuffle_training_data|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|missing_values_handling|enum|expert|MeanImputation|
|quiet_mode|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|autoencoder|boolean|secondary|FALSE|
|sparse|boolean|expert|TRUE|
|col_major|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|average_activation|double|expert|0|
|sparsity_beta|double|expert|0|
|max_categorical_features|int|expert|2147483647|
|reproducible|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|export_weights_and_biases|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|mini_batch_size|int|expert|1|
|categorical_encoding|enum|secondary|OneHotInternal|
|elastic_averaging|boolean|expert|FALSE|
|elastic_averaging_moving_rate|double|expert|0.9|
|elastic_averaging_regularization|double|expert|0.001|
|export_checkpoints_dir|string|secondary|·|
|auc_type|enum|secondary|AUTO|

This script worked without an issue for three or four checkpoints. I inspected the imported model and rebuilt my checkpoint script to completely match the definitions. The more specific checkpoint script did not change the behavior, so I tried to import the prior checkpoint model and unfortunately I get the same error. I also tried R-4.2.2, I also tried running h2o as a single node.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).